# Higchart to set hidden value

Tags: highcharts

In Highchart I use piechart to show student details with name and marks in the chart.In this chart to I need pass student number also.But that student number I need to store hidden value not need shown chart i.e In pie chart to show student name and total marks only When I click the chart to pass get  the student name with roll number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a point as an object with additional properties.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            hiddenValue: 'hidden value'
        }, {
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/emdm3a26/